# How to copy the value from one text box to another text box from differnt two forms vb.net2008?

Tags: vb.net

I use the panel in the form, the panel contains one text box and the form contains another text box. When I click OK button the panel, ill hide.and the form ill show, the value of text box in panel is transfer to the another text box in the same form. pls help me anybody.

Comment: Helped me, I was trying to use = Me.Text, but that's the form, not the text box.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

In the button click event simply:-

Text2.Text = Text1.Text

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood correctly, I made a small example
 Hello Fabrizio

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
       <div>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Testo 1"></asp:Label>
         &nbsp;
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
    </asp:Panel>


      <div>
         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Testo 2"></asp:Label>
         &nbsp;
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>

      <div>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
      </div>

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim str1 As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Me.Panel1.Visible = False
        Me.TextBox2.Text = str1
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Shared Function GrabURL(ByRef value As String) As String
    If (value Is Nothing) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return Regex.Match(value, "(http://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?)").Value
    End If
End Function

' if empty string is added:
FForm2.ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(GrabURL(RichTextBox1.Text)))

' if empty URL should be ignored:
dim lviURL as New ListViewItem(GrabURL(RichTextBox1.Text))
if lviURL .Text <>"" then FForm2.ListView1.Items.Add(lviURL)
```